# NetSuite and SuiteTalk list all of a type (paged or not)

Tags: soap, netsuite, suitetalk

I am currently trying to work with the [SuiteTalk 2017_2_0 API](https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2017_2_0/netsuite.wsdl) for a new integration with NetSuite.  I have all the basics rolling of single record retrieval, etc.; however, I am having a problem trying to figure out how to list all of a given object/type in the system.

Example:  I want to list ALL InventoryItem data.

Not sure what I am missing.  Does anyone have a sample SOAP doc?

**What I did so far**

I have been working primarily with types:  Sales Order, Customer and Inventory Item.

1. Tried using the `getAll` call defined in the WSDL - only supports limited fields:

   - budgetCategory
   - campaign*
   - currency
   - etc.
2. Tried using `getList` but a set of internal IDs are required in the `baseRef`/`RecordRef` (*INVALID_KEY_OR_REF - The specified key is invalid.*)

Fails:

```
<urn:getList>
  <urn1:baseRef xsi:type="core:RecordRef" type="salesOrder" />
</urn:getList>
```

Succeeds:

```
<urn:getList>
  <urn1:baseRef xsi:type="core:RecordRef" type="salesOrder" internalId="1" />
  <urn1:baseRef xsi:type="core:RecordRef" type="salesOrder" internalId="2" />
</urn:getList>
```

3. Tried formulating a search that would return all the data but the types I need are unavailable (or I haven't been able to figure it out)

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: Right now I'm just using SoapUI to post raw.    The rest I added to the entry above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a saved search that pulls the appropriate data, then call the saved search.

Comment: That would be fine but I was hoping to avoid having to do anything inside NetSuite itself.  Unless I can create the saved search and use `getSavedSearchRequest` to retrieve the request.  Let me give that a shot.

Comment: You can code up the search in web services, too, but it’s easier to define it in the UI and call it from your code. It also performs better.

Comment: I have to change the data in the "Results" tab to get what I needed, but it worked.

Comment: Of course it did. It’s actually a great/preferred way to do this. If your criteria ever changes, change your search, not your code.